# Copy object, not being able to change the texture on one?

Tags: texturing, objects

I have a Villager, rigged and everything, and when I copied him, the two were, exactly alike. Like expected.
But when I tried to change the texture on one, the texture on both changed.
I tried adding another texture to the object, but whatever I do, they stay the same. Its like they are the same object, just separated.
How can I change this?
I tried to make a "share the blend" file but it says it was too big.